# union is merging results

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

i have a query that looks as following:

```
(SELECT title FROM pjeducations LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT title FROM pjeducations WHERE animal != "all" LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT title FROM pjeducations ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Some of the results in the second select are the same as in the first, same with the third select.

The problem is that the duplicate results automaticly get removed but i would like them to stay in it. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

Use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Works perfect, reaction was so fast that i have to wait 13 minutes to accept your answer, tyvm for the fast reply

Answer (score 3):

```
Union All
```

preserved duplicate results

Comment: Personal choice, but when I post an answer and find it's a duplicate that doesn't add anything beyond the earlier one, I remove it.

Comment: i do the same, but sometimes an answer gets posted while i am writing my answer so i dont get to know if they are duplicates

Comment: @Microgen: Sure you do, they're right there when you save your answer. Happens to me all the time, I do my answer, click save, and find that someone else said exactly the same thing, so I click delete. (Off-topic: If you reply to someone's comment, put "@username:" at the front so they get notified.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: and if someone gave the same answer as you, but sooner, I think it is worth upvoting theirs after you delete yours. It's almost like voting for yourself :)